# Past Simple/Present Perfect. Result or fact?

Tags: present-tense

The Oxford English Dictionary *chose/has chosen* the neologism 'omnishambles' as its Word Of The Year for 2012.

It's a result. It was chosen. And is true now. In my opinion it's better with Present Perfect. But my private tutor says it's a fact about the past, so it should be Past Simple. I need opinions of English gurus.

Comment: For a fairly short (but hard to define exactly) time after OED chose the word, 'has chosen' would have been the idiomatic choice, though 'chose' could have been used in certain contexts ('You don't think it's a word? Well, OED chose it as Word of the Year [yesterday], so it must be.") But by 2016, 'chose' is the idiomatic choice (though again, 'OED has chosen the neologisms 'omnishambles', 'selfie', 'vape' and ':-)'  as 'Word Of The Year' in recent years.) shows that one shouldn't be over-prescriptive.

Comment: Also useful: [How to correctly use the present perfect tense](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/25709/how-to-correctly-use-the-present-perfect-tense)

Answer (score 1):

As your sentence refers to a far past (the year 2012) past tense would be the normal thing. If you say "X has been chosen as word of the year", then it is news up to now not known to readers or persons spoken to.