# Two different meanings of Present Perfect Tense

Tags: meaning, differences, ambiguity

I have a problem in the interpretation of the following sentences in the **present perfect** tense.

> 1) I have worked for them since 2006.

Does it mean *I am still working for them* or *I don't work for them any more*?

> 2) I have lived in this house since 2006.

Does it mean *I am still living in the mentioned house* or *I don't live in this house anymore*?

EDIT: Please note that there is time expressions in both sentences.

Comment: Related question, [How do the tenses and aspects in English correspond temporally to one another?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21846/how-do-the-tenses-and-aspects-in-english-correspond-temporally-to-one-another) and [Present Perfect usage](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/73666/present-perfect-usage).

Comment: Another related question, [Which is correct: “has died” or “died”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/63256/which-is-correct-has-died-or-died).

Comment: @Rathony Thank you. Can you please answer my question? I really need to know them.

Comment: Your question is not easy to answer, but It is not that difficult to search your answer in any grammar book or on the internet. Did you read all the links? I think there is an answer.

Answer (score 2):

The default interpretation of these sentences is that they exhibit the *continuative* or *universal* perfect, which represents the state designated by the lexical verb as continuing throughout the designated timeframe up to the present. A hearer assumes that they mean that you are still working for the company and still live in the house.

However, this interpretation is an *implicature*, not an *entailment*—it may be **cancelled** by other conditions within the discourse context. If that is the case, the sentences will be reinterpreted, probably as *existential* or *experiential* perfects, which represents the eventuality designated by the lexical verb as having occurred at least once before the present. For instance:

> A lot of people say that H&P Systems has become very unfriendly and exploitative to freelance programmers since Phil Sartorius became CEO in 2006. But I have worked with this company since 2006, on several occasions, and have never encountered anything to complain of.

There are also *resultative* or *stative* perfects, which represents the eventuality designated by the lexical as having occurred at least once before the present and having given rise to a state which still obtains in the present; but it is difficult to conceive circumstances in which a stative verb like *live* gives rise to another state. Here's a marginal possibility:

> Your notice states that anyone who lived in the house after the industrial in 2006 is eligible for compensation from the defendant. I have lived in the house since 2006—for three months in 2010—and believe I am therefore eligible for this compensation.

Some authorities also recognize a *recency* or *hot-news* perfect; but the scholar who first proposed this, James McCawley, subsequently withdrew it as a special case of the others.